# Retrieving certain numbers with regex

Tags: regex

I need help getting certain numbers with a regex.
As I dont know much about regex I have only managed to see if the first two characters match with 95 - 99. ^([0-9][5-9]{4})

I have the numbers 00000 through 99999.

I want to exclude all the numbers that start with 95 and up.

So 00000 - 94999 is ok, 95000 - 99999 is not ok.

Comment: Which language? Why do you need regex for this? It's much more manageable without it.

Comment: Regex is not well suited to doing numeric comparisons. If the number is in other text, then extract it and compare.

Comment: You can use `^(?:[0-8]\d{4}|9[0-4]\d{3})$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could match the range of numbers 00000 - 94999 including leading zeroes you might try it like this:

- `^` From the beginning of the string
- `(?=\d{5}$)` Start with a positive lookahead that makes sure that the number is not longer than 5 digits until the end of the string
- `0*` Preprend with zero or more zeroes
- `(?:9[0-4][0-9]{3}|[1-8][0-9]{4}|[1-9][0-9]{1,3}|[0-9])` Match the range of numbers
- `$` The end of the string

Your regex could look like:

[`^(?=\d{5}$)0*(?:9[0-4][0-9]{3}|[1-8][0-9]{4}|[1-9][0-9]{1,3}|[0-9])$`](https://regex101.com/r/700uRS/1)

Answer (score 0):

A regex is for validating if a string matches the set pattern.  It is not for comparing numbers to see if they are within range.  Convert the text (if that is what you are starting from) to a number and then use comparison operators in an if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Regex is not well suited to performing numeric comparisons, from both a readability and performance standpoint. It would be much more sensible to extract the number and perform a numeric compare afterwards.

You've not mentioned a language, so I'll demonstrate with Python3.

```py
# input data
lines = [
    "my line #1 :94995: message #1",
    "my line #2 :95005: message #2"
]

for i, line in enumerate(x):

    # extract a 5-digit number wrapped in colons
    match = re.search(':([0-9]{5}):', line)
    if match is None:
        continue

    # convert to a number, and verify
    num = int(match.group(1))
    if num >= 95000:
        continue

    # print any lines that meet our criteria
    print("line %d meets our criteria! (%d)" % ( i, num ))
```

Will output:

```
line 0 meets our criteria! (94995)
```